How to get pro*c to build a 64 bit application in Oracle 19.9
I am working on a 32 bit application which I need to port to a 62 bit architecture. It is a C application and Ive done the requisite -m32 to -m64 changes for all the C code. But however, the current failure point in my compilation is the pro*C precompilation part which is failing with these sort of errors:
    proc DEFINE=HS_EXT_HDR_II hold_cursor=no release_cursor=yes sqlcheck=full userid=XXXXXXXXXXXXX iname=DB

Pro*C/C++: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jun 3 07:26:20 2024
Version 19.9.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /data/oracle/product/19.9_client/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Syntax error at line 166, column 45, file /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:
Error at line 166, column 45 in file /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
#define __glibc_fortify(f, __l, __s, __osz, ...) \
............................................1
PCC-S-02014, Encountered the symbol "..." when expecting one of the following:

   an identifier, define, elif, else, endif, error, if, ifdef,
   ifndef, include, include_next, line, pragma, undef, exec,
   sql, begin, end, var, type, oracle,
   an immediate preprocessor command, a C token, create,
   function, package, procedure, trigger, or, replace,

This is how the proc command is run in the makefile:
proc DEFINE=HS_EXT_HDR_II hold_cursor=no release_cursor=yes sqlcheck=full userid=XXXXXXXXX iname=DB

Can anyone please help me what other options are needed or anything else to be done for the precompiling to go through? I am not much aware of pro*C precompiling and doing this for the first time.

Those errors don't sound like they are 32 vs. 64 bit related. It sounds like the pre-processor doesn't like something in your code. Are PTQUERY and AUDIT_OPERATION database objects? If so, are they owned by the user you are connecting as? If not, can you qualify them with the object owner?

Thanks @PaulW. I have updated the actual errors got at the start. All I've done is compiled with 64 bit options  and changed ORACLE_HOME to a 64 bit version from an earlier 32 bit version.

Also see this discussion, maybe. And possibly this question.
